# Woocommerce кнопка В корзину, вместо Выбрать

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Создан вариативный товар и кнопка `В корзину` поменялась на `Выбрать` и ведёт на товар. Нужно, что была стандартная кнопка. Испробовал массу вариантов. Нашёл в ядре, где эта функция вызывается, но как её изменить - не понял

```
 woocommerce\templates\loop\add-to-cart.php

echo apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', // WPCS: XSS ok.
    sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ), // тут генерируется ссылка
        esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
        isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
    $product,
    $args
);
```

Шёл дальше по функции `add_to_cart_url`, но без толку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если товар вариативный, то откуда WooCommerce знать, какой товар класть в корзину? Надо выбрать сначала на странице товара.

Comment: @IgorR.Я вывел вариацию в том же месте, делаю выбор - ничего не меняется.

Comment: Ответ был найден тут:
https://aceplugins.com/how-to-add-a-quantity-field-to-shop-pages-in-woocommerce/ Нужно удалить код из документации, который добавляет количество в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

А так?

Вы смотрите в фильтр ссылки, а нужно смотреть в фильтр текста кнопки `esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', function( $text ) {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $text = $product->is_purchasable() ? __( 'Custom options text', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $text;
}, 10 );
```

Comment: Всё равно не изменилась ссылка

Comment: @РомаХр Тогда почему у меня работает? prnt.sc/tk4me8

Comment: Потому что у меня ещё выведено количество товара видимо. Код брал отсюда https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons/ . Так не работает

Comment: Я убрал && $product->is_type( 'simple' )  из условия

Comment: Если это не работает, то скорее всего проблема в теме или кеширование. Попробуйте почистить кеш браузера. На чистой теме работает отлично.

Comment: Возможно плагины мешают некоторые, но отклчюить их я не могу. Нашёл другое решение. Вместо Вашего кода и того, что я брал на оф сайте. https://aceplugins.com/how-to-add-a-quantity-field-to-shop-pages-in-woocommerce/